# Uglify after browserify - global variables lost

Tags: node.js, browserify, uglifyjs2

I am using this command at my package.json:

```
"compile": "browserify js/Initial.js -o build/bundle.js",
"postcompile": "uglifyjs --source-map build/game.bundle.js.map --source-map-url game.bundle.js.map -mt -o game.bundle.js build/bundle.js"
```

Inside Initial.js, I have this:

```
var ConfigPosition = require('./config/position');
```

And position file is like:

```
module.exports = 
{
 spinAnimationBasicControls: 
 {
    speed: 10,
 }

};
```

The problem is, ConfigPosition gets lost after uglifying, because it ends up not being in global scope for some reason? What happens here?

Answer (score 0):

```
global.ConfigPosition = require('./config/position');
```

did the trick to me;

Comment: Please explain where this should go and why it works.